# What should be done with parsed text before inserting it to DB by SQL?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

In reasons of speed increase I decide to use raw SQL. So, with ActiveRecord I had 17714 ms for fill DB, now I have 1730 ms. Good, isn't it? But here is one problem, texts are different from each other and some of them don't want to go to my DB. By the way, with same groups of posts I hadn't problems when work with them through AR.

```
insert_arr = []
  walls.each do |wall|
    wall['items'].each do |post|
      if post['text'].empty?
        post['text'] = 'репост'
      else
        post['text'] = post['text'].slice(0, 100) + '...'
      end
      insert_arr.push "('#{@group[:id]}', '#{post['id']}', '#{post['date']}', '#{post['text']}')"
    end
  end
  sql = "INSERT INTO posts (`group_id`, `post_id`, `post_date`, `post_text`) VALUES #{insert_arr.join(', ')}"
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

I've tried to slice the text, it's not help. But if I remove text at it works just fine! `post['text'] = ''` So, the problem is here. Please, help me. What should I do with text before insert it?

Comment: you need to read up about [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: @MarcB Here is no user's input. All data is validated before...

Comment: irrelevant. you're still inserting "outside" text into a query string. doesn't matter WHERE that text came from. any sql metacharacters (quotes in particular) will cause syntax errors. even if the payload isn't bobby-tables-style malicious, it's STILL an injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of above try to use the regular ActiveRecord way, but enclose all the inserts bulk with transaction:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  # put your inserts here
end
```

it will avoid SQL commits after each `INSERT` saving lots of time.

Comment: I know about transactions, but have not try with current task because I know that raw SQL is much faster... Just because your answer I decide to try, to show you the time of inserting in this case. I can't believe! It shows 1157 ms!!! It's cool! Thanks man!